# Java arrays effective use/alternative

Tags: java, arrays

This is simple code which should demonstrate point of my question.I don't know if there are some more effective implementations of arrays than this one.What makes them so uncomfortable to me is that we have to write condition into `if()` block for each element and that makes code much longer.Is there any way how to include all elements of certain array in one line? Thank you!

```
public class test{
  static String[] text;

public static void main(String args[]){
     text=new String[5];
     text[0]="hello";
     ...
     text[4]="bye";

     if(text[0].contains("something")==true||...text[4].contains("something")==true)
          //do something     
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to check for containment, or equality? I mean will this value be true - `"asf something ABC"`?

Comment: My bad sorry, I wrote this code fast

Comment: You don't need `== true` in there. You could use `text[0].contains("something") || ...` and it would work the same way.

Comment: @JohnSmith. I think you misunderstood my comment. I meant, should `text[0]` just contain `something`, or should it be equal to `something`?

Answer (score 4):

Either use a loop:

```
for (String item: text) {
    if (item.contains("something")) {
       // TODO condition
    }
}
```

... or use an ugly workaround, such as:

```
if (Arrays.toString(text).contains("something")) {
    // TODO condition
}
```

Comment: I think only the first version is correct.`Arrays.toString(["c", "a", "r"]).contains("car") -> true`

Comment: @arshajii thanks, will fix for-loop now :)

Comment: @rendon nope. Try initializing a `String[] car = new String[]{"c", "a", "r"}` and printing the `Arrays.toString(car)`.

Comment: But there could still be issues if the string you are searching for is `","`, `"["` or `"]"`.

Comment: @arshajii that's why it's called an "ugly workaround". The 1st for-loop in my answer is what I'd normally use.

Answer (score 2):

You can write your own method to do that:

```
public static anyContain(String[] array, CharSequence sub) {
    for (String s : array)
        if (s.contains(sub))
            return true;

    return false;
}
```

Then the `if`-statement will be

```
if (anyContain(text, "something")) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the best way (only for full equals of elements):

```
text=new String[5];
...
if (Arrays.asList(text).contains("something")) {
  // you code here
}
```

If you need test for `contains` you can also do:

```
String[] test = new String[] {"one", "two", "something", "three"};
Arrays.sort(test);
int index = Arrays.binarySearch(test, "something", new Comparator<String>() {
  @Override
  public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
    return o1.contains(o2) ? 0 : -1;
  }
});
```

As result you also get an index of element in array. Or negative value if not found.

Comment: That doesn't check if the individual strings contain `"something"`, it just checks if the array itself contains it.

Comment: @arshajii: you right, i just fix my answer